# How to convert .ASE or .ACO color swatch files to .PNG — ONLINE?

Tags: color, swatches, file-conversion, palette

Can't find this anywhere, tried the popular online converters.

How do I easily convert `.ase` or `.aco` to `.png` online?

Comment: You really shouldn't edit to add an answer within the question. either provide a separate answer yourself or select a correct answer form the supplied answers. I assumed you had enough Stack rep to understand how Stack works. You've basically just edited the question rather than marking my answer as correct.

Comment: @scott - you're right, I wasn't thinking. I edited the question back to its original and I'll accept your answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ase and aco files are **not** images. They are application code of color definitions within Adobe applications.

There *may* be a way to convert them directly to images, but I think that may be unlikely since the ase/aco formats are proprietary.

There are some online tools to display the colors. Such as ...

- For **ASE**: https://carl.camera/sandbox/aseconvert/
- For **ACO**: https://aco-viewer.appspot.com/

You could then take a screenshot to get a PNG.

I also found this: https://www.reaconverter.com/convert/ase_to_png.html for ASE 2 PNG, but it requires the download of software. I don't, in any way, vouch for this software. There are additional software downloads out there and a simple internet search will present them.

<sub>These URLs were merely cursory finds via an internet search. There may be better tools out there. I have no affiliation with either link.</sub>

Comment: NOTE: This one works for converting .ase `https://carl.camera/sandbox/aseconvert/` … but this one does NOT work: `https://aco-viewer.appspot.com` because it adds additional colors and gray borders which mess up your screenshot (your palette would contain additional unintended color)